# Question on Probability of passing an Exam

Tags: probability

There is a set of $N$ questions in a question bank out of which $M$ questions are placed in an exam paper. In order to pass the exam, I have to do at least $1$ question, and I only prepared $T$ questions from the question bank. What is the probability of passing the exam?

---

For example : $N = 4, M = 2, T = 1$

Answer : $1/2$

Comment: So the criterion for passing is to get $1$ out of the $M$ questions right?

Comment: yes right......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some implicit assumptions here.  For example, you are assuming that you will answer a question correctly if and only if you have prepared for it beforehand.  (In reality, you might solve a problem for the first time during an exam, or you might mess up a question that you have previously prepared for.)  You also probably want to assume that the questions are drawn uniformly randomly from the question bank.  Anyway, going with these assumptions, here is a solution.

The number of ways that they could have chosen the questions is given by the binomial coefficient $\binom{N}{M}$.  The number of ways that they could have chosen *none* of the questions that you prepared for is $\binom{N-T}{M}$.  Therefore, the probability you will fail is

$$ \Pr[\text{fail}] = \frac{\binom{N-T}{M}}{\binom{N}{M}} = \frac{(N-T)!(N-M)!}{N!(N-T-M)!} $$

The probability you will pass is therefore

$$ \Pr[\text{pass}] = 1 - \frac{\binom{N-T}{M}}{\binom{N}{M}} = 1 - \frac{(N-T)!(N-M)!}{N!(N-T-M)!} $$

Comment: what if N-T-M become less than 0 like for eg 10 9 7

Comment: If $N-T-M < 0$ then ${N-T \choose M} = 0$, i.e. it is impossible to fail.

Answer (score 0):

$P(\text{passing the exam}) = 1-P(\text{the question that the person studied does not appear on the exam})\\ = 1-\frac{{3 \choose 2}}{{4 \choose 2}}= \frac{1}{2} $

Comment: I think that the numbers given were just an example, and the OP wants a general solution in terms of $N$, $T$, and $M$.